# Passing Text box value to RDLC Report as a parameter in C#.net

Tags: c#, printing, reporting, rdlc

I am working on a desktop application in C#.net and using RDLC Report. 
I want to print text box values in report, but after setting parameters in RDLC and passing the values to report in report viewer, my printed report gives this error:

> the "parameter_name" parameter is missing a value

I have tried all ways but could not find the solution of this problem. 
Kindly help me out.
 Code to add parameter and the error which my report is showing is attached in pics.

[image: Error in RDLC Report image]

[image: Code to add parameter image]

Comment: Debug the program . is something missing in param? If not either .text is empty or you're doing something wrong when creating the objects

Comment: Text box has the value.. check the qhole program wiyh dubugging.. parameter is set correctly but still the problem is same..

Comment: Found the error - when i make the object of the form, then all the controls at that form attain their default value and text box value sets to default empty string, thats why report is showing missing parameter value error..

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I think your problem can be solved starting from here.
Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to show the DataSet of the RDLC report, then choose the parameter properties that you are looking for.